# How mongodb select only data which all array's values coincide data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this two datas.

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5e2564e7fc4adf6813df71fa"),
"product_nums" : [ 
    {
        "product_number" : "123123qwedf2",
        "product_status" : "F"
    }
]}
{"_id" : ObjectId("5e2570d20b83102cad7adf04"),
"product_nums" : [ 
    {
        "product_number" : "123123qwedf",
        "product_status" : "S"
    }, 
    {
        "product_number" : "123123qwedf2",
        "product_status" : "F"
    }
]}
```

I want get only first data. when i search by filter product_status = "F"

This is my query :

```
db.getCollection('product_number').find({"product_nums" : {"$elemMatch" : {"product_status": "F"}}})
```

But that query return second data also.

How can I get this only :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e2564e7fc4adf6813df71fa"),
"product_nums" : [ 
    {
        "product_number" : "123123qwedf2",
        "product_status" : "F"
    }
]}
```

Comment: Here is an example on how to query for a specific array element: [Use the Array Index to Query for a Field in the Embedded Documen](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#use-the-array-index-to-query-for-a-field-in-the-embedded-document).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
db.getCollection('product_number').aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        data: { /** filter returns [] if input array has only F's */
            $filter:
            {
                input: '$product_nums.product_status', /** $product_nums.product_status = ['F'], ['S','F'] */
                as: "each",
                cond: { $ne: ['$$each', 'F'] }
            }
        }
    }
}, { $match: { data: [] } }, { $project: { data: 0 } }])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2564e7fc4adf6813df71fa"),
    "product_nums" : [ 
        {
            "product_number" : "123123qwedf2",
            "product_status" : "F"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2570d20b83102cad7adf04"),
    "product_nums" : [ 
        {
            "product_number" : "123123qwedf",
            "product_status" : "S"
        }, 
        {
            "product_number" : "123123qwedf2",
            "product_status" : "F"
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e291efcd02e05b694d18244"),
    "product_nums" : [ 
        {
            "product_number" : "123123qwedf2",
            "product_status" : "C"
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f93bad02e05b694989468"),
    "product_nums" : [ 
        {
            "product_number" : "123123qwedf",
            "product_status" : "F"
        }, 
        {
            "product_number" : "123123qwedf2",
            "product_status" : "F"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2564e7fc4adf6813df71fa"),
    "product_nums" : [ 
        {
            "product_number" : "123123qwedf2",
            "product_status" : "F"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f93bad02e05b694989468"),
    "product_nums" : [ 
        {
            "product_number" : "123123qwedf",
            "product_status" : "F"
        }, 
        {
            "product_number" : "123123qwedf2",
            "product_status" : "F"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey @srinivasy, I am wondering, is it possible to use projection to limit with _id and product_nums value based on product_status. Though your solution revolves around the answer, what in case there is multiple key-value pair and only he needed that 2 elements. If you would have a projection to this query. It makes lot of sense.

Comment: @Balaji.J.B : This query would only return `_id` & `product_nums` even though documents has more fields, in case if he need remaining fields he need to specify all needed fields in projection !!

Comment: Thank you for detail explain and sample. I tried that. But i got different result which i want. 
I mean, I want to get only Objectid(5e2564e7fc4adf6813df71fa) at your collection datas. 
Because ObjectId("5e2570d20b83102cad7adf04") has "S" product_status. sorry my bad English explanation.

Comment: The answer before the fix was also very helpful !! It solves my another problem. Thank you!